# Convert Negative Numbers in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const numbers = [200, 450, -400, 3000, -650, -130, -70, 1300];
```

I want all negative numbers in this array to be Positive. How can I do that using Javascript?

```
//OUTPUT const numbers = [200, 450, 400, 3000, 650, 130, 70, 1300];
```

Comment: Is it possible using ForEach ? Thank you guys !

Comment: No you cannot use `forEach` as it will only iterate it and does not return an array.

Comment: `numbers.map(Math.abs)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `map` with `Math.abs()` to get the number's absolute value?

```
const notNegative = numbers.map((num) => Math.abs(num));
```

Since OP asked, you can use `forEach`, too, but you'd need to `push` results to a second array:

```
let notNegative = [];
numbers.forEach((num) => notNegative.push(Math.abs(num)));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write it even shorter:

```js
const arr=[200, 450, -400, 3000, -650, -130, -70, 1300];

console.log(arr.map(Math.abs));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use absolute provided by `Math` as `Math.abs()` to convert all number into absolute number i.e. on positive side (whole number)

```js
const numbers = [200, 450, -400, 3000, -650, -130, -70, 1300];
output=numbers.map(e=>Math.abs(e))
console.log(output)
// [200, 450, 400, 3000, 650, 130, 70, 1300]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Array#forEach` and `numbers[i] = ...` if you do not want to create a new array; by definition the `Array#map` method creates a new array.

```js
const numbers = [200, 450, -400, 3000, -650, -130, -70, 1300];

numbers.forEach((elm,i) => numbers[i] = elm < 0 ? -elm : elm);
//OR numbers.forEach((elm,i) => numbers[i] = Math.abs(elm));

console.log( numbers );
```